# get first and last values for each condition

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('534343df3232'),
    date: ISODate('2016-01-08T00:00:00Z'),
    item_type: "book",
    book_id: ObjectId('534343df3232fdf'),
    user_id: ObjectId('534343df3232fdf23'),
    rating: 6
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('534343df3232'),
    date: ISODate('2016-01-05T00:00:00Z'),
    item_type: "movie",
    movie_id: ObjectId('534343df3232fdf'),
    user_id: ObjectId('534343df3232fdfa'),
    rating: 5
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('534343df3232'),
    date: ISODate('2016-01-010T00:00:00Z'),
    item_type: "song",
    song_id: ObjectId('534343df3232fdf'),
    user_id: ObjectId('534343df3232fdf13'),
    rating: 9
}
```

There can be only one rating per item per user per day.

I would like to check how the ratings evolve between a period of time for a selection of users and items. I need only the first and the last rating for each book/movie/song.

I have no idea on how I could do this the most efficient way.

As for now, I'm retrieving all the ratings for all the users, and then parsing them with PHP.

```
db.ratings.find({user_id:{$in:[...]}, $or:[book_id:{$in:[...]}, song_id:{$in:[...]}, movie_id:{$in:[...]}, ], date:{$gte:.., $lte..}  });
```

This is obviously unefficient but I don't know how to handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with mongodb [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/). So at first you need to filter your data on date range, selection of users and selection of items(query part). Then group by item(map part) and for each item select first and last days with corresponding ratings(reduce part).

Try the following query:

```
var query = {
  user_id: {$in:[...]}
  date: { $gte: dateFrom, $lt:dateTo},  
  $or: [
    {book_id: {$in:[...]}}, 
    {song_id:{$in:[...]}},
    {movie_id:{$in:[...]}}
  ]
}

var map = function () {   
  emit(this.item_type, { 
    first : {rating: this.rating, date: this.date}, 
    last: {rating: this.rating, date: this.date} 
  }) 
}

var reduce = function (key, values) {     
  var res = values[0];     
  for (var i=1; i<values.length; i++ ) {         
    if (values[i].first.date < res.first.date) 
      res.first = values[i].first;          
    if (values[i].last.date > res.last.date)             
      res.last = values[i].last;     
  }     
  return res; 
}

db.collection.mapReduce( map , reduce , { out: { inline : true }, query: query } )
```

Comment: Sorry I may not have explained it well, by "min" and "max" I meant: the closest values to the edges within the date period (i.e. the first and last values), because there may not be ratings on some days. This is where I'm stuck, because the begin/end dates may not be exact.

Comment: @512banque Sorry for misunderstanding. I've updated my answer.